# Multidimensional Arrays in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsdictionary

I have an `NSDictionary` filled with data. If this was php it might be accessed by  something like:

```
$data = $array['all_items'][0]['name'];
```

How do I do something similar in objective c? (`$array` would be an `NSDictionary`)

Comment: I think data here is NSArray, in which is NSDictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent code in Objective-C is:

```
id data = [[[array objectForKey:@"all_items"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"name"];
```

Note that `objectForKey:` is a method of NSDictionary, and `objectAtIndex:` is a method of NSArray.

A shortcut in Xcode 4.5, using LLVM 4.1, is:

```
id data = array[@"all_items"][0][@"name"];
```

Also note that if "array" is an NSDictionary instance and you want to get an array of all values in the dictionary, you use the `allValues` method of NSDictionary:

```
id data = [array allValues][0][@"name"];
```

Of course, `allValues` returns an unsorted array, so accessing the array by index is not very useful.  More typically, you'd see:

```
for (NSDictionary* value in [array allValues])
{
    id data = value[@"name"];
    // do something with data
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the objective-c version is not as elegant syntactically as the PHP version:

```
NSDictionary *array = ...;
NSArray *foo = [array objectForKey@"all_items"];
NSDictionary *bar = [foo objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *data = [bar objectForKey@"name"];
```

For brevity, you can do this on a single line as:

```
NSString *data = [[[array objectForKey@"all_items"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey@"name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use it,

```
NSString *value = [[multiArray objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:0];
```

You can look the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596593/multi-dimensional-nsarray-object)