# Match clicked TableView row (string) to find corresponding unique ID

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am currently stuck on how to best find and pass the ID of a clicked table view row. I'd like to know what the best practice might be to accomplish this.

- In an iPhone storyboard I want to create a **`tableview`**.
- This tableview should get populated from a **JSON** web server response.
- This JSON object will contain around **10 items**, say name and
  address plus a unique ID.
- In my tableview I'd like to have in each tableview row one name
  and address but I don't want to have the unique ID displayed.

Now here comes **my question**: If I don't have the unique ID displayed how do I find this ID again based on which row has been clicked? Is there a way of assigning hidden fields? I'd like to **send the unique ID via POST** back to web server.

The directions I've been investigating in so far are...

- ...parse JSON object into `NSDictionary` and match clicked tableview row back to it to get ID.
- ...put JSON object into SQLlite database and match clicked row against database to get ID.
- ...don't do any of the above and simply **send a string of name and address** (instead of ID) back to web server where the matching against database would take place.

What do you think will be best in terms of getting the corresponding ID from a clicked tableview row.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can accomplish this

Call your webservice and get the json. Parse the json and keep on adding object to a NSMutableArray say itemList.

Create a model class say Itemdesc which will have 3 fields name, address and ID.

When you parse your json extract each individual product into item model object defined above and add it to itemList array.

It could be like this:

```
NSArray *responseArray = responsefromService;
For(int i=0;i<responseArray.count;i++)      
    {
        //Parse your object here
        NSDictionary *currentItem = [responseArray objectAtIndex:i];
        Itemdesc *itemObject = [[Itemdesc alloc] init];
        itemObject.name = [currentItem objectForKey:@"name"];
        itemObject.address = [currentItem objectForKey:@"address"];
        itemObject.ID = [currentItem objectForKey:@"ID"];
        [itemList addObject:itemObject];
        itemObject=nil;
     }
```

Now pass this array as object to tableView for row count and in cellForRowAtIndexPath get your row object as below:

```
Itemdesc *currentIndexObj = [itemList objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
cell.name.text = currentIndexObj.name;
cell.address.text = currentIndexObj.address;
```

This will display your name and address in your tableViewCell.

To get the ID when a row is select, in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath write below code:

```
Itemdesc *currentIndexObj = [itemList objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
NSString *ID = currentIndexObj.ID;
NSLog(@"ID  value: %@", ID);
```

You have got your ID, perform whatever operation you want to perform.

Model Class is nothing but simply a normal Class itself.
Code to create a Model Class:
  Go to File -> New -> File ->iOS-> Source -> CocoaTouch Class

select next and given Class a name ItemDesc and make it subclass of NSObject. In your project you will get to files Itemdesc.h and Itemdesc.m

Itemdesc.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Itemdesc : NSObject
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *name;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *address;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *itemID;
```

@end

No need to make any changes in .m file.
Thats it. Import the header in your class where your tableView exists and things will work.

Json structure:

```
[
    { 
         "name" : "John", 
         "address" : "ny",
            "ID" : "xyz"
    },  
    {
            "name" : "Jane",
            "address" : "dc",
            "ID" : "pqr"
    } 
]
```

Comment: Thanks Arun for your answer. Could you explain or point me toward a tutorial on how to create this model class that stores name, address and ID? Thank you :-)

Comment: Updated my answer with Model Class also. Its same as you create normal class and subclasses with NSObject.

Comment: Thanks a lot Arun. Could you please elaborate a little bit on how you expect the incoming JSON to look like which you then parse and add to the object? How do you create the relation in `*responseArray`? Thank you very much for your great help!

Comment: Thanks again Arun but how do I create the `NSArray *responseArray` from this JSON (`responseFromService`)? Would I create a [multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596593/multi-dimensional-nsarray-object) or how would you do this?

Comment: I can't answer you on how this is created at server side on device just see examples ofvAFNetworking which directly provide you json like responsrFromService which you can  ditectly assign to nsarray.

Answer (score 1):

I *simplest* way to accomplish this is to store the objects you get into a local array (or anything that has order and matches the display order of the table). From there you can just use the index of the table cell that was selected, to determine which object was selected and grab the ID.

So, if you have an array of sampleObjects (each of a name, address and ID) populated from your web service. Use this array as the datasource for your table. Use the [tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:) delegate method as follows...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    int rowSelected = indexPath.row;
    id sampleObject = tableDataSource[rowSelected];  // Assuming tableDataSource is an array you created to populate the table
    // ...do whatever with the object that the user selected
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically you have a collection of model objects that determine how many UI elements to show to the user.  In the simple case this could be just an `NSArray` but could also be fetched from Core Data or a remote backend.

As the table asks for cells, use the `indexPath` to look up the corresponding model object in the backing collection.  You can then use the information in the object to configure the cell.

When the user selects a row, you can use the reported `indexPath` to do a similar lookup.  Once you have the correct object, you can look up its ID and perform the necessary network request.

Answer (score 1):

Lets make it in steps.

1. Start downloading JSON
2. Save JSON data in some Array/Dictionary what ever you like, here i will use responseData as name of my Collection.
3. Your tableView rows are responseData count.
4. in cellForRowAtIndexPath populate you data, only that you needed, address name, but your responseData still have id for each object, right?
5. in didSelectRowForIndexPath, you will get the id somehow like this

> Swift

```
resonseObject.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey(id)
```

> Objective-C

```
[[responseObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"id"]
```

You also can make custom UITableViewCell class and put the ID as String Property and set it in cellForRowForIndexPath, but i think the first solution is better.

Greetings.